# Is it legal and possible to trample someone with a controlled mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, mounted-combat

In 5th edition, mounted combat with a controlled mount limits the actions of your mount into the Dodge, Dash, and Disengage actions. However, what about charging at someone and trampling them? Intuitively, it seems like it should be possible. However, I can't find any rules to support this, or any to provide support for a reasonable ruling.

There is a [similar question but without an accepted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/can-a-mount-attack-while-it-is-being-ridden) of the more general case, in which it is asked if the mount can attack while being ridden. This question is more specific in that I am asking if you can have the mount trample someone while you are controlling it (so it does not have its own initiative).

Comment: Are you open to mounting an animal companion?

Comment: @daze413 Sure, but that answer limits it to the Ranger class only. A more general answer would also be nice :)

Comment: What if you rule out the ranger animal companion by linking to [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55349/23064), and saying you know animal companions can do it.

Comment: Are you asking about mounts with a Trample action option, or just mounts in general?

Comment: @Miniman Mounts in general. I imagine those with a Trample action will be easier to support, but be the mount a Pegasus or a regular horse, they could still intuitively and purposefully collide with someone or something while being controlled and ridden.

Comment: @daze413 I'd rather not rule out any specific mounts, since there isn't a strong reason to do so. The question seems to me to be specific and well-formed enough as it is, pending any potential close votes :). Answers can certainly reference that for the case of Ranger Beast Masters though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, if you control your mount, it can't trample someone. You said it yourself:

> it has
>   only three action options: Dash, Disengage, and Dodge.

None of those includes trampling. You might be thinking that you can trample enemies just by moving through them, but that's not how it works.

> You can move through a nonhostile creature’s space. In
>   contrast, you can move through a hostile creature’s space
>   only if the creature is at least two sizes larger or smaller
>   than you. Remember that another creature’s space is
>   difficult terrain for you.

Moving through enemies doesn't do damage to them, or knock them prone, or anything else like that. Here's how trampling works in D&D 5e:

> ***Trampling Charge.*** If the horse moves at least 20 feet straight
>   toward a creature and then hits it with a hooves attack on
>   the same turn, that target must succeed on a DC 14 Strength
>   saving throw or be knocked prone. If the target is prone, the
>   horse can make another attack with its hooves against it as a
>   bonus action.

This particular example is taken from the Warhorse statblock, but many monsters (such as elephants and mammoths) have similar abilities. Even a mount that has this ability won't be able to use it while being controlled, since it requires them to use their *Hooves* action, which they can't do.

Comment: Technically, the warhorse needs to take the *Hooves* action. It can take an attack action but it's options are limited to an unarmed strike or a shove (without a hand it can't grapple).

Comment: @DaleM Good point, that would be the Hooves action. Editing.

Comment: @Miniman What if you used your action (not the mount's) to make an attack, but using the mount? Do you think it's plausible?

Comment: @markovchain [We have a question about using other creatures to make attacks.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95181/15469) As for plausible, that's not something I can answer.

Comment: @Miniman Hmm, this is a different scenario from what is presented in that question though. I'm not sure grappling your horse and using it to swing at your opponents, while funny, is plausible.

Comment: One solution might be to have the mounted PC conduct her normal melee attack, then merely 'describe' the damage as coming from a trample.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like an improvised action (see Improvising an Action, pg 193, Player's Handbook) with a animal handling check to control the animal during a risky maneuver, DC based on Animal Training and/or Int.